# SIGCONT not detected by channel

Tags: go

I'm trying to replicate a shell environment. The following code runs within `os.StartProcess` and `p.Wait()`. It is able to receive `C-z` (SIGTSTP) and `C-c` (SIGINT) but not when I send `SIGCONT` from another shell with `kill -CONT [PID]`.

```
sigChild := make(chan os.Signal)
defer close(sigChild)
signal.Notify(sigChild, syscall.SIGTSTP, syscall.SIGINT, syscall.SIGCONT)
defer signal.Stop(sigChild)

sigRcvd := <- sigChild
fmt.Println(sigRcvd)
```

I'm not sure if I missing something in my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's an known issue in Go. There is an issue for it on [GitHub](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/8953).